# Should I grant customers product access on PAYMENTS.PAYMENT.CREATED or PAYMENTS.PAYMENT.COMPLETED on paypal webhooks?

Tags: paypal, webhooks

I have been using PayPal webhook responses to verify that customers have paid for a product, and it appears evident that the `payments.payment.created` webhook arrives before the `payments.payment.completed` webhook. I'm told (by chatGPT) that the `payments.payment.completed` webhook actually means that the funds have been transferred and the customer has safely paid, whereas the `payments.payment.created` webhook simply means that the user has engaged in a financial payment but may not have necessarily finished. Is this correct? And if so, is it safe to grant a user access to my product on the arrival of the `payments.payment.created` webhook, because the `payments.payment.completed` webhook takes literally 5-10 minutes to arrive which is problematic for the nature of my service.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For one-time payments, the correct solution is to not wait around for asynchronous events like webhooks. Your integration should not rely on them, except perhaps for future events like refunds, disputes or subscription payments that happen on a schedule.

Instead, all one-time payment PayPal API integrations have the equivalent of a "capture" API call which gives immediate notification of success/failure. Use this.

See the [standard checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide. It gives example backend code in node, but that can of course be implemented in any environment including python.

---

For subscription integrations that make payments happen on a schedule, the relevant webhook is `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`